# how to create a duplicate local administrator group in Win XP?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions

how to create a duplicate local administrator group in Win XP? I want to create a group same with local administrator group in Local Users and Groups under Computer Management. I know how to create a group in Computer Management but i don't know how to give the group the same access and power as local/build in administrator group.

Answer (score 2):

To do that, simply add the new group as a Member Of the Administrator group.  That would give anyone in it local admin rights.